# Second method cant use variable of property

Tags: c#, class, properties

Im new to this stuff so I might have a fundamental misunderstanding and I hope someone can clear it up for me. I have looked for similar topics but I didn't find a clear answer.

Code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp37
{
    class Propertything
    {
        public int number1 = 5;
        public int test
        {
            get { return number1; }
            set { number1 = value; }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Propertything x = new Propertything();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.number1);
            x.number1 = 25;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.number1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    class SecondMethod
    {
        public void Method2(string[] args)
        {
            SecondMethod y = new SecondMethod();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", y.number1);
            y.number1 = 33;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", y.number1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is the CS1061 Error I get because of these lines (the number1):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", y.number1);
y.number1 = 33;
Console.WriteLine("{0}", y.number1);
```

My thought process was that a property (the first class) is used for cases where multiple classes use the same variables.
I expected the result to say: 5 25 5 33.

can someone explain why the second class (`class SecondMethod`) is not able to use the variable `number1` like the class `Program` ?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. `y` is of type `SecondMethod` that doesn't have a `number1` property.

Comment: First off: don´t call your **class** `...Method`. Second: Your `SecondMethod`-class does not know anything of `number1`, which is declared in `PropertyThing`. Why do you think those two classes know anything about each other?

Comment: SecondMethod y = new SecondMethod();, you created a instance class itself. To use it, you need to use Propertything y = new Propertything();

Comment: I dont know how I could have missed that part I was looking at that thing for like 20 minutes. I was so confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because property `number1` is in `Propertything` not in `SecondMethod`.

You create

```
SecondMethod y = new SecondMethod();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", y.number1);
```

Not, like in main method,

```
Propertything x = new Propertything();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", x.number1);
```

You can use `Propertything` in `Method2` or add property

```
public int number1;
```

to `SecondMethod`

Comment: Oh thank you I completely missed the difference between the 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's beause your class `SecondMethod` does not contain a variable or property with the name `number1`

```
class SecondMethod
{
    public void Method2(string[] args)
    {
        SecondMethod y = new SecondMethod();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", y.number1);
        y.number1 = 33;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", y.number1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It is inside your other class